# ReactJS Persistant Sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, reactjs, dragula

I am building a web app using ReactJS and am having difficulty with persistant sorting.  The application is for company use only and is essentially a employee task manager (similar to [Pivitol Tracker](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/)).  It manages 6 employees, each employee has a column and the tasks run down that column in a vertical list.

The idea is to allow drag & drop sorting of tasks, which is then synced to the server (using [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/)) and the change is made to all running applications.  I have the UI built, and every feature (add, edit, delete, etc..) is functional, but I cannot figure out how to do the sorting.

I am building each task as such:

```
var tasks = this.props.tasks.map(function(task) {
  if(!task.archive) {
    return <Task key={task.id} id={task.id} ...more props />
  }
});
```

Then I simply call `{tasks}` in my Render function to output the html.

I found an interesting plugin [Dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula) which has enabled the drag and drop feature, but I need some ideas on how I can make this persistant.  I've tried to capture the order of the tasks IDs in an array, and then sort the returned map data but was unsuccessful.

How can I accomplish this task?  I am relatively new to ReactJS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an example at https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns React.14/DragAndDrop. Some here;

```js
let list = [
  {id: 'l1', label: 'first line of list'},
  {id: 'l2', label: 'second line of list'},
  {id: 'l3', label: 'third line of list'},
  {id: 'l4', label: 'fourth line of list'},
  {id: 'l5', label: 'fifth line of list'},
  {id: 'l6', label: 'sixth line of list'},
  {id: 'l7', label: 'seventh of list'},
  {id: 'l8', label: 'eighth line of list'},
  {id: 'l9', label: 'nineth line of list'},
  {id: 'l10', label: 'tenth line of list'},
  {id: 'l11', label: 'eleventh line of list'},
  {id: 'l12', label: 'twelth of list'},
  {id: 'l13', label: 'thirteenth line of list'},
  {id: 'l14', label: 'fourteenth line of list'},
  {id: 'l15', label: 'fifteenth line of list'}
]

class DndCtrlRender extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let isMobile = this.props.isMobile;
    return (
      <div id='DndCtrlSty' className='FlexBox' style={DndCtrlSty}>
        <DList data={list} isMobile={isMobile} />
        <DList data={this.state.list} dndDone={this.dndDone} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class DndCtrl extends DndCtrlRender {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {list: _ld.cloneDeep(list)};
    this.savedItemID = '';
  }
  dndDone = (startID, endID) => {
    let newList = this.state.list;
    let startObj = _ld.findWhere(newList, {id: startID});
    let startIndex = _ld.indexOf(newList, startObj);
    newList.splice(startIndex, 1);
    let endObj = _ld.findWhere(newList, {id: endID});
    let endIndex = _ld.indexOf(newList, endObj) + 1;
    newList.splice(endIndex, 0, startObj);
    this.setState.list = newList;
  }
}
```